# Revoking 1 token revokes all tokens of same OAuth Client ID + User Consent Pair

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm experiencing a situation where:

I have a Google project, using an OAuth 2.0 Client (for web applications), to get consent for some scopes from users. The [authorization parameters](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient) used in the redirect to Google uses the following values for the parameters (only including the possibly relevant params):

- `access_type` - `offline`
- `response_type` - `code`
- `include_granted_scopes` - `true`

If a user consents access to the app, the app gets an access token to access the scopes granted.

If the same user consents again (while the previous access token hasn't been revoked yet) to the same app (using the same OAuth 2.0 Client), a new access token gets issued to the project.

The Google project has 2 **different** tokens now, and both access tokens work for accessing the scopes granted. Oddly though, the user would see only a single entry for the Google project/app in the users [Apps with access to your account](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) page.

The issue is that if any of the [token gets revoked](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke), all of the active tokens get revoked (attempts to use the access token results in an `invalid_grant` error, with the `Token has been expired or revoked.` error description). While I haven't tested beyond having 2 live/valid tokens at the same time, I suspect the behavior would be the same for more than 2.

I've been looking through the Google OAuth 2.0 docs to find some documentation regarding this behavior, or find anything referencing what happens to companion tokens when one gets revoked, but was unable to find anything explaining this behavior.

I, at first, thought that it was maybe due to my usage of [incremental authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#incrementalAuth), and thought that maybe revoking the latest access token revokes all preceding ones, but after experimenting with `include_granted_scopes=false`, the behavior was still the same.

For now, I've restricted users to be able to consent only once (unless a token expires), but I'm curious about the explanation for this behavior - where revoking 1 token revokes all of them.

Comment: One of your application's responsibilities is to validate tokens. For tokens that you want to  **revoke**, store them and then issue an error such as 401 if there are used. Also, note that tokens expire after 3,600 seconds so your app does not need to remember them forever. There is also a limit to the number of tokens that can be issued per account. Once that limit is reached the oldest tokens are revoked. There is nothing wrong with a user having multiple tokens with different authorization levels (scopes). Your app decides which tokens the user uses.

Comment: I agree the token-revoke documentation is not clear regarding this behavior. Nowhere does it say that all tokens (all access) will be removed but in reality that is what happens.
>The token can be an access token or a refresh token. If the token is an access token and it has a corresponding refresh token, the refresh token will also be revoked.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually access tokens are independent.  An access token by design will work for one hour.  In theory even if the user revokes your access the access token will still work for the remainder of the hour it was originally valid for. This is standard Oauth2 functionality they are intended to give access for an hour that is why it is called a bearer token the bearer of that token is granted access for an hour.

What i suspect that you are seeing is the refresh token being revoked as this will cause a invalid_grant error.  If you request access of the user using offline access you are granted a refresh token.  If you request consent of the user again you get another refresh token.  There can be up to fifty outstanding refresh tokens for a single user.

If the user revokes the access via their google account, or if your application revokes the access. Then yes all of the outstanding refresh tokens will be revoked.  As your applications access to the users account has been revoked not the single refresh token.  Note there are actually serval reasons why a refresh token can expire they can be found here [refresh token experation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

This is standard Oauth2 behavior not google specific.

[Remove third-party account access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521#remove-access)

> If you gave Google Account access to a third-party app or service you no longer trust or want to use, you can remove its access to your Google Account. The app or service won’t be able to access any more info from your Google Account, but you may need to request that they delete the data they already have.

Comment: My unofficial observation is that revoked tokens start to fail within a couple of minutes globally. The process is definitely not **instant**.

Comment: @JohnHanley nothing in this world is instant.  it takes time for things to be processed by googles authorization server.  it depends a lot on how busy the server is that you are revoking it on is.   Also doing it on a full hour i would expect that would also make it slower as a lot of the servers are slow at that time due to automated cron jobs.

Comment: I was commenting on this part of your answer ***In theory even if the user revokes your access the access token will still work for the remainder of the hour it was originally valid for.***

Comment: In my experience with Authorization servers in general including the ones i have maintained personally (Identity server4).  By default access tokens will continue to work for the hour even if they consent itself was revoked.  It would be an extra check on behalf of any api to do policy type check again to ensure that the access had not been revoked.   Bearer tokens by default are considered self contained.

Comment: Most apis assume that if you have one that the berar token grants you access for its lifetime they dont do an additional check at the time that they are used to ensure that you still have access.    This is why access tokens have a short life time because they cant be revoked.   [Self-Encoded Tokens](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/listing-authorizations/revoking-access/)

Comment: I am only commenting on Google Authorization and not how other systems are implemented. IdentityServer and Google Accounts are entirely different systems and implementations.

Comment: >Actually access tokens are independent. --- if they're independent why does revoking one revoke all of them?

Comment: @Alexey you cant revoke an access token they are self contained and work until they expire.   You can revoke a Refresh token which is completely diffrent and and this will not prevent existing access tokens from working.

Comment: Linda, check the docs (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke) you can specify either access or refresh token for revocation. Although the result is the same, all outstanding tokens of your app get invalidated and your app loses all access.

Comment: Maybe Google has a bug there because the docs are not clear about this behavior and we'd like to have the option to revoke just the access token we specify.

Comment: You can use an access token or a refresh token to revoke a users access to your app, it states it will also revoke the refresh token access.    Nothing in there says that an existing  non expired access token will stop working.  because they are self contained.

Comment: I know, nothing like that is said there! But that is the behavior. That is our point! I've been retesting this yesterday and today. I do OAuth flow, get one token, then I do another OAuth flow and get another token. I revoke one of them, the other one is revoked too.

Comment: As a matter of fact I may have 10 tokens obtained independently though OAuth flows for the same mailbox. I remove one of them, all go bad (invalid_grant / expired)!